# Client unable to connect to server with socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm having trouble with being able to connect to my node.js server from an external domain. It works fine when running it locally using the http web server through node however when connecting externally, it loads the `socket.io.js` file just fine but when trying to use the socket it removes the port from the URL and cannot connect.

Instead of doing this in the network requests:

http://external-domain.com:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M06GOUU

it does this:

http://external-domain.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M06GOUU

I'm not sure how to make it not remove the port from the connection. How do I go about fixing this?

**SERVER**

```
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');

const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, '../public');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = socketIO(server);

app.use(express.static(publicPath));

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log(`Server is up on port 3000`);
});
```

**CLIENT SCRIPT TAG**

```
<script src="http://external-domain.com:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

**CLIENT JS ON A DIFFERENT DOMAIN**

```
var socket = io();

socket.connect('http://external-domain.com:3000');

socket.on('connect', function () {
  console.log('Connected to server.');
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change from this:

```
var socket = io();
socket.connect('http://external-domain.com:3000');
```

to just this:

```
var socket = io("http://external-domain.com:3000");
```

And, you don't use the `socket.connect()` as you will already have requested the connection with the `io("http://external-domain.com:3000");` call.

---

**Explanation**

The code:

```
var socket = io();
```

uses the page URL to connect to a socket.io server at that origin.  That is not what you want (apparently).

If you wanted to use the `.connect()` method, it would be like this:

```
var socket = io.connect("http://external-domain.com:3000");
```

Note: `var socket = io(url)` is simply a shortcut for `var socket = io.connect(url)`.

[`socket.connect()`](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/master/docs/API.md#socketconnect) does not accept a URL as a parameter so you simply weren't using that correctly.  It's just a synonym for `socket.open()`.

Comment: Oh wow, that works, thank you! Just curious, what is the difference between the two?

Comment: @FirstLegion - More explanation added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use io.connect("url")

```
var socket = io.connect("http://external-domain.com:3000", { rejectUnauthorized: false });
```

`// { rejectUnauthorized: false }` is an optional parameter.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a problem with it being rejected as it's just not finding the correct URL.